# Typing something in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I basically what to use BeautifulSoup to login to my stocks account on a website so that I can add it to my stock application and make it so that the app would buy/sell the stock depending on how the price increases or decreases throughout the day. When I was **scraping** through the website to login, I realized that I am not aware if you can even type or fill in the text in BeautifulSoup. To be more clear, let's say we have a login and a password bar which I want to type my username and password in. I scrape both search bars using BeautifulSoup but now I want to type my username and password in the fields. How can I do this? Also if BeautifulSoup cannot do this, are there any other modules that I can use to just simply log in for me?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but I would strongly advise you not to do automatic trading like that - many, MANY things can go wrong

Comment: yeah lol thats most definetly agreed but what I have in my program as well is a limit so that my application does not buy more than that price ever. It doesn't matter if the prcie of the stock is greater than it and I am getting a huge profit. I have also made a test account with just a couple hundred bucks in case things go the other direction. Also I'm kinda doing this for my resume too.

Comment: @JackJones take a look at the [robots.txt](https://www.td.com/robots.txt). What do you see there?

Comment: does that mean that auto submission isn't allowed like how I am doing it on selenium?

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium for this (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), together with beautiful soup:

https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-99195cd70a58

Comment: yes! I originally tried using selenium as that's what I personally prefer over BeautifulSoup but the issue that I have is that when I log in to the website using selenium, it doesn't let me in and just gives me a error when logging in. I am using TD WebBroker if you were wondering. When I login in Chrome normally it works fine but when i automate it using selenium it didn't work. Thats why I am trying to figure out if BeautifulSoup allows me to login :/

Comment: Have you installed the chromedriver ?